# net connection using cdma WLL BSNL phone

Tags: internet, modem, edubuntu

Please help me in connecting the WLL cdma bsnl phone in edubuntu software supplied by it@school

> the model name of wll cdma connection is HUAWEI FP2255
>
> the hints
>   * when the device is connected by usb cable to lap a link is shown in mobile brandband (see the attached photos)
>
> *when i searched in google hemanathan's blog and some others lead me to write the programme in "terminal"
>
> but i cant do it
>
> suggest simple ways

>

Answer (score 2):

Let me know which version of Ubuntu you are using (Edubuntu is a derivative of Ubuntu).

If you are using Ubuntu 10.4 or higher it will detect the device automatically. You will have to create a **Mobile Broadband Connection**:

1. Click on the **Network Connection** icon on the top panel.
2. Click "**Edit Connections...**"
3. Select "**Mobile Broadband**" tab.
4. Click "**Add**".

   Here you will:

   - Select the **device** and click **Continue**.
   - Select **Country** and click **Continue**.
   - Select **Provider** and click **Continue**.
   - Select "**my plan is not listed**" and enter any **APN** and click **Continue**.
   - for the **dialup** string use **#777**.
   - enter your **username** and **password** given by **BSNL**.
   - Click **Apply**.
5. Now again left click on network icon. You will now see your connection under Mobile broadband.
6. Click on it to connect.

That's all.

Comment: Ubuntu has also  ability to detect modem if you use older version than 10.04